# Add subscribers to given list along with an interest group mail chimp VB

Tags: vb.net, mailchimp

I want to add interest group to the subscribed user programatically in mailchimp. I have four check boxes i am able to get the first name email and other details but not the Group named Area. is there any way that i could check the check box in that form

I have tried like this but not worked.

[image]

```
 Dim mcApi As MailChimp.MCApi = New MailChimp.MCApi(apiKey, False)

    Dim options = New MailChimp.Types.List.SubscribeOptions()
    Dim lstinterr = mcApi.ListInterestGroupings("7c785ac86f")
    options.DoubleOptIn = True
    options.EmailType = MailChimp.Types.List.EmailType.Html
    options.SendWelcome = True


    Dim intrestGrop = New MailChimp.Types.List.InterestGroup("1", "Northern Beaches / North Shore", 1, 264)
    Dim groupingList = New MailChimp.Types.MCList(Of MailChimp.Types.List.InterestGroup)()

    groupingList.Add(intrestGrop)




    Dim grouping1 = New MailChimp.Types.List.InterestGrouping(4777, "Area", MailChimp.Types.List.GroupingType.Checkboxes = 1, 0, groupingList)

     Dim mergeText = New MailChimp.Types.List.Merges("sillyvolley@gmail.com", MailChimp.Types.List.EmailType.Text) From {{"FNAME", "Hareesh"}, {"LNAME", "Eeram"}, {"PWD", "Eeram"}, {"GROUPINGS", grouping1}}
    Dim merges = New List(Of MailChimp.Types.List.Merges)() From {mergeText}


    Dim batchSubscribe = mcApi.ListBatchSubscribe(listId, merges, options)
```

Even c# would do for me if not in VB. Thanks